# Python Based Network Sniffer

Tags: python, network-programming, network-protocols, scapy

I am working on developing script which will monitor network traffic and analyse network traffic by dissecting raw http packets.

For getting this work done I think scapy will be right thing to start am worried about scalability and performance any suggestion ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture raw network traffic, [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) (or [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/))  is your friend. It's the standard library for packet capture, and it's what scapy itself uses.

If you want to use it with python, there are [wrappers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap).